# Visual studio - gtkmm-app - MSVCP100D.dll is missing

Tags: visual-studio-2012, dll, gtkmm

I cannot execute my gtkmm-app any longer in visual studio 2012. It compiles fine but when executing it crasches. I get the error message that **MSVCP100D.dll** is missing.

I made this app in visualstudio 2010 last spring. OS was windows XP. No problem whatsoever.

Now I have visualstudio 2012 and windows 8.1 and get this error-message.

I dont know what to do? Is there a way to install MSVCP100.dll in the system-folder or could something be done in VS 2012?

I may underline that I just encountetred this problem when compiling and executing my gtkmm-app for the first time since the platform change and IDE-update. Ordinary console-applications no problems whatsoever.

If you also have time/knowledge - what is the purpose of this dll-file?

Comment: You can recompile or re-install gtkmm in Visual studio http://gtkmm-installation.blogspot.com/

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error probably because you changed your compiler.
What you can do is to either recompile gtkmm with current Visual Studio or download pre-compiled binaries and rebuild your application.

Option 2 is to install Visual Studio 2010 back and forget about Visual Studio 2012.
If you want both latest Visual Studio and gtkmm 3 then...
It's not an easy task, and it's hard to answer your question in detail here, so
Here is an [tutorial](http://gtkmm-installation.blogspot.com/) to let you get started compiling/installing gtkmm 3 in Visual Studio 2013 for Windows 7 and later: